# 誰に聞いても何も教えてくれない

Tags: translation, nuances

The sentence “誰に聞いても何も教えてくれない。” was translated as “No matter who I ask, nobody tells me anything.”

Could it also mean “No matter who you ask, no one will tell you”? As a warning or in a sarcastic manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it could -- ***easily***.

Who it is that is asking or responding just depends on the context.